# windows mail stopped working with GMail

Tags: windows-10, email, gmail

I like the windows mail app for it's speed and simplicity, but seems like since end of march or around that it is unable to download email from google. I have removed and re-added the account but it did not help. 
I got email on my alternative email that application Windows was granted access to a connected google account.
There does not seem to be any advanced settings available.

Comment: Still works on my machine.  You have enabled insecure applications within your Google account?

Comment: no, have you? Do I have to?

Comment: Yes; I have enabled it and have no trouble with Windows Mail retrieve mail from my Google Mail account.

Comment: so the Windows mail is less secure application? Wonderful :-]
Anybody can confirm this is required?